# Simplify the html element into js

Tags: javascript, html

I am making bunch of elements that look like the same

I have

```
<div id="e1" class="e1">

        <div class=box>
            <div class='b1'></div>
            <div class='b2'></div>
            <div class='b3'></div>
            <div class='b4'></div>
        </div> 

    <div class='e11'></div>     
    <div class='e12'></div>     
    <div class='e13'></div>     
    <div class='e14'></div>     
    <div class='e15'></div>                                     
        ...more elements
<div>


<div id="e2" class="e2">

        <div class=box>
            <div class='b1'></div>
            <div class='b2'></div>
            <div class='b3'></div>
            <div class='b4'></div>
        </div> 

    <div class='e11'></div>     
    <div class='e12'></div>     
    <div class='e13'></div>     
    <div class='e14'></div>     
    <div class='e15'></div>                                         
        ...more elements
<div>
```

They are almost the same and I have several `e3` and `e4` div...

MY question is if there are anyways to reduce the codes and create them in js with an object (or better approach).

Would anyone gives me a hint? Thanks a lot!

Comment: what is your objective? Reducing code can't be your only reason?

Comment: Just as a note, you shouldn't re-use "id" values on multiple elements ("box").  You can use "class" instead.

Comment: You're looking for _HTML templating,_ server-side or client side. Do some research with that term.

Comment: @Sebas yes Sebas, I am trying to reduce the cumbersome of the same type of elements. for Pointy, Sorry it was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B5pnv/)**

You are going to need to get some iteration parameters, and then make a function which iterates based on those parameters to create these html elements. The primary way do create an html element is

```
document.createElement("tagname");
```

and then you are going to need to append them in the order you wish. Once they are done, you can append them to an element on the screen. Avoid appending inside of a loop. Even if you create a lot of elements, they will render quickly if they are only appended onto the screen once instead of each time an element is created.

Here is a simple example:

```
<div id="contentZone"></div>
<script>
 var c = document.getElementById("contentZone");
 var content = document.createElement("div");
 for( var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
  var d = document.createElement("div");
  d.innerHTML = i + ") Hello :D";
  content.appendChild(d);
 }
 c.appendChild(content);
</script>
```