# Javascript functions in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, random

I was tasked by my professor to make a simple Javascript program that displays simple math problems and their answers in a two dimensional table using a random number. Previously he gave us the example of using a function to write into a table like this:

```
function RandomGen() {
Random = math.floor(Math.random()*60);
    document.writeln("<th>");
       document.writeln(Random);
       document.writeln("</th>");
}
RandomGen();
```

In order to use an array, can I do this?

```
var RandomArray [

RandomGen(),
second_function(),
third_function(),
forth_function(),
]

RandomArray[0];
```

How do I append the functions together to write into a table?

Comment: Are you trying to store functions into an array and then run them from the array?

Comment: yes, and have the function write the html as well, at the professors request.

Answer (score 3):

You almost got it. The correct syntax is:

```
var randomArray = [    
  RandomGen,
  second_function,
  third_function,
  forth_function
];

randomArray[0](); // this calls RandomGen
randomArray[1](); // this calls second_function
```

Remember the basic syntax rules:

1. A function name with no paranthesis is a function reference. It behaves just like any reference and so can be treated as a variable. Which means you can assign it to another variable, pass it into another function and as the example above stuff it into an array.
2. Adding paranthesis `()` to a function reference causes the function to be called. It doesn't matter if the function reference is a plain old function name or stored in another variable or stored in an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the function in a variable, then put the variables in an array, and then access them from the array to call them.

```
var add = function(x,y){ return x + y; };
var multiply = function(x,y){ return x * y; };
var maths = [];
maths.push(add);
maths.push(multiply);
maths[0](1,2);//3
maths[1](3,4);//12
```

Conversely, you could do this with an object.

```
var maths = {};
maths.add = function(x,y){ return x + y; };
var four = maths.add(1,3);
```

Obviously you will have to modify these to match your exact situation.

Comment: gotcha, how would i then write into a table?

Comment: I keep pressing enter sorrylol document.writeln("<th>") maths[0](1,2); document.writeln("</th>")?

Comment: @user2210274 - If you wanted `maths` content in the `document.write` it would be `document.writeln("<th>"+maths[0](1,3)+"</th>");` where the `+` sigh concatenates the strings together. That would result in writing `<th>4</th>` to the page.

Comment: do you know how you would then print an element inthe array to the DOM into a html element using getelementbyid?

Comment: @user2210274 - You would use the `document.createElement` and `.appendChild` methods. Here is a simple example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15580994/1026459